does dotnet-trace Thread Time "Exc %" include Jit time?
I am using dotnet-trace collect -p <processorid> --providers Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime to troubleshoot an issue in an online application. While analyzing the generated nettrace file, I am confused about the meaning of the Exc % metric in Thread Time. The official explanation is "The exclusive cost expressed as a percentage of the total cost of all samples."
However, it is not clear whether this "samples" includes JIT time. Can someone help clarify this for me? Thanks.
